# Override cd command to save absolute path to bash zsh history

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there a simple way to go about this? I'm trying to override the `cd` command so that in bash history, it shows up as `cd <absolute_path>`. The original command does not show up in history.

Comment: `bash` or `zsh`? They are two very different shells.

Comment: Regardless, interactive shell configuration (as opposed to script development) is a better fit for [unix.se] than here.

Comment: @chepner preferably `zsh`, but I figure I'd open this up to either since I'm looking for general approaches

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe it should be moved to Unix&Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the effect you want:

Before:

```
/Users/fred> cd ..
/Users> cd
/Users/fred> history
...
438  cd ..
439  cd
440  history
```

After:

```
/Users/fred> source gash.sh      #   Magic happens here
/Users/fred> cd ..
/Users> cd
/Users/fred> history
...
501  source gash.sh
502  cd /Users
503  cd /Users/fred
504  history
```

You can use a function in `bash`, here defined in 
gash.sh:

```
# Must be 'sourced'

cd() {
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        builtin cd                # This calls the shell version of cd
    else
        builtin cd "$@"           # This calls the shell version of cd
    fi
    msg="cd $(pwd)"
    history -s "$msg"             # This writes to the history 'file'
}
```

EDIT:

In `zsh` replace the `history -s` (which `zsh` does not have) with `print -s`.  The problem then is that both the typed command and the new command appear in the history.  You might be able to get around this by using `fc -p` and `fc -P`, but it seems like quite an overhead to get around this.

Your comment that you want a general solution is unlikely to be satisfied, the history systems on both shells are driven by different commands.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it working using `zshaddhistory`, but I was hoping you could answer this: To remove duplicate `cd`s, I actually return so that it won't propagate to `$HISTFILE`. The hijacking `cd` with the absolute path is used then I do `fc -p` to push it to history. However, `$HISTFILE` doesn't contain it. Will this cause some sort of side effects?

EDIT: I actually got them to sync by removing `fc -p`.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with `zsh`, so I can't comment on side effects, but are you sure it is not waiting in a buffer to be written to the history file?